# NGINX location case insensitive

Tags: nginx, location, case-insensitive

I'm setting up a multisite web server with nginx, but I'm having a problem with managing subsites.
In practice, if I call up my web server with the url http://host/bollettini I can navigate the site correctly, but if by mistake I enter an uppercase character in the url (for example http://host/Bollettini or http:/ /host/BOllettini) nothing works and a 404 error is returned.

```
location ~* ^/bollettini/$ {
  return 301 $scheme&:$host/bollettini;
}

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}

location /bollettini/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /bollettini/index.php?$args;
}
```

Could you give me some suggestions?

Comment: You have a typo in your return statement, it should probably be: `return 301 $scheme://$host/bollettini/;` or more simply `return 301 /bollettini/;`

Answer (score 0):

The order of RegEx `location` blocks is important, because the first RegEx match is used:

```
# Lowercase RegEx matches first
location ~ ^/foobar/ {
  return 200 OK;
}

# Case-insensitive match is otherwise used
location ~* ^/foobar/(.*) {
  return 301 /foobar/$1;
}
```